# creating html reusable blocks via shortcodes

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, functions, shortcode

I'm using a really simple and fast theme in order to reach a good speed score,
so i'm not using any visual composer, but writing my own sections in pages via html

i have some sections and cta that i'd like to repeat identical around the site so i had the idea of placing the html for each block inside a shortcode and then in the pages i just paste the shortcode for them where i need em.

first of all, is this a ok practice?

secondly, in terms of page loading speed is it ideal as i did to create these shortcodes (which will inject html in the dom basically) in my child-theme function.php or should i create a plugin with all the shortcodes instead?

Answer (score 0):

It's an OK practice but in some cases could be turned to a worst case scenario!
Using shortcodes to generate blocks of HTML is the reason they exist, especially when you need some dynamic HTML generation (using attributes in the shortcode).

In conclusion, a normal shortcode usage is totally OK, however you should avoid putting hundreds of shortcodes in one page, otherwise it causes poor performance on the website.

Comment: thanks, i indeed ended up creating them only for repeatable sections, like 4-5 at max on some pages, but i created a dedicated php file for all the shortcodes, to keep the function.php cleaner, and the site rolls a 92/100 mobile PSI right now, with woocommerce and all, for a starter plan shared hosting ain't bad

Comment: Yeah that's totally fine.
P.S Forgot to congrats you on joining the community :)